# Como posso criar minha própria folha de estilo?

Tags: css

Como posso criar minha própria folha de estilo? Assim como o CSS. É possível criar a minha própria folha de estilo como o CSS? Existe outra folha de estilo além do CSS? Se sim, como?

Comment: Não ficou claro. Você quer personalizar sua página com CSS próprio ou quer criar uma nova linguagem de estilos?

Answer (score 0):

Voce precisaria criar nao apenas a sua folha de estilo, mas um browser proprio e/ou integracoes pros browsers atuais interpretarem sua folha de estilo, o que nao parece ser uma boa ideia.

No entanto, o que já existe atualmente são pré-processadores de CSS, como [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), [Stylus](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiGme-khIrUAhWFEpAKHQyWBBEQFggkMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstylus-lang.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNEqQJD6KjPRi4g8tYZwoVGCWi_vKQ&sig2=LesJdz251OhdfN4VXg9MhA).. Neles voce escreve codigo nessas "linguagens" que depois sao compiladas para CSS, para que os browsers interpretem a sua folha de estilo.

[Pergunta muito similar no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/925679/3473971)